# How to Properly Implement API Authentication with Devise in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, devise, devise-jwt

I'm building a Rails API and am trying to implement authentication using Devise. My goal is to use JWT tokens for authentication, but I'm encountering issues with the sign-in process and generating/responding with tokens.

I've overridden the Devise::SessionsController to handle JSON requests and respond with JWT tokens upon successful authentication. However, I'm facing a `NoMethodError` with `users_url` during the sign-in process, likely due to Devise attempting to redirect, which is not applicable for API responses.

```bash
NoMethodError at /api/v1/users/sign_in
======================================

undefined method `users_url' for #<Api::V1::SessionsController:0x000000000587f0>

> To access an interactive console with this error, point your browser to: /__better_errors
```

Here's how I've currently set up my Api::V1::SessionsController:

```rb
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    if resource
      token = generate_jwt_token(resource)
      render json: { user: resource.as_json, token: token }, status: :created
    else
      render json: { error: 'Invalid email or password' }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def generate_jwt_token(user)
    # :) 
  end
end
```

`devise.rb`

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'info@example.com'

  require 'devise/orm/mongoid'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :params_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12

  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 8..128

  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  config.responder.error_status = :unprocessable_entity
  config.responder.redirect_status = :see_other

  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :json]

  config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = Rails.application.credentials.devise_jwt_secret_key
    jwt.expiration_time = 1.day.to_i
  end

end
```

**Questions:**

How can I properly implement the sign-in process in `Api::V1::SessionsController` to avoid redirection attempts by Devise and ensure it's suitable for API use?
What's the best practice for generating and handling JWT tokens with Devise for Rails API authentication?
How should I structure the JSON response for sign-in and sign-out actions to make it more consumable by the front end?

Any advice on correctly setting up Devise for API authentication or pointing out what I might be missing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you actually need to use JWTs, I would stick with cookie-based authentication and opaque session tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise against building your own auth system.

Since you are already using Devise, I would suggest using https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt

> devise-jwt is a Devise extension which uses JWT tokens for user authentication. It follows secure by default principle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also suggest devise-jwt.

If ur app is an apy_only just make sure to set false to store at devise.rb

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.scope_defaults :user, store: false
end
```

Prevent unwanted redirects on login and ActionDispatch::Request::Session::DisabledSessionError: Your application has sessions disabled